# Programmatically Updating Inventory source

Tags: magento, magento-2.3

I am currently working on a magento2.3 MSI. I've installed MSI and I'm now trying to work on it. I've created 3 sources and 1 stock. I need to assign stock to sources. Currently I've created csv importer for importing stocks but during this process I also want to assign source name to existing products. For example: I've sources like source1, source2 and source3 and I want to assign not only updating quantity and stock status but also the source name.

I had used this code:

```
$product->setStockData(['qty' => 4,'manage_stock' => 1,'source_code' => 'source1','name' => 'My source 1','is_in_stock' => 1]);

$product->setQuantityAndStockStatus(['qty' => 4,'manage_stock' => 1,'source_code' => 'source1','name' => 'My source 1','is_in_stock' => 1]);
$product->save();
```

The qty and is_in_stock is working well but not able to update source name to assign to that product.
Is there any wrong with this code? Or is there any other method to deal with this.
If anybody knows the solution that would be really appreciable.  Thanks!

Here is my model source code:

```
public function execute(array $data)
{

    /**
     * @var Product $product
     */
    $product = $this->productRepository->get($data[self::CSV_SKU]);

    /** @var StockItemInterface $stockItem */
    $stockItem = $this->stockRegistory->getStockItem($product->getId());

    $attributes = [];

    $product->setStockData(
        [
            'qty' => 4,
            'stock_id' => 1,
            'manage_stock' => 1,
            'source_code' => 'source_1',
            'name' => 'My Store 1',
            'is_in_stock' => 1
        ]
    );
    $product->setQuantityAndStockStatus(
        [
            'qty' => 4,
            'stock_id' => 1,
            'manage_stock' => 1,
            'source_code' => 'source_1',
            'name' => 'My Store 1',
            'is_in_stock' => 1
        ]
    );
    $product->save();

    $stockItem->setUseConfigManageStock(1);

    $this->stockItemRepository->save($stockItem);
    $this->action->updateAttributes([$product->getId()], $attributes, 0);

    return $product;
}
```

The expected result is to assign the source to that product like in the image below:

[image]

But source is not assigned to that product.

Comment: I have followed this link https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/rest/modules/inventory/manage-source-items.html and did as per this but no luck.

Comment: I have solved that error adding some codes like this:public function execute(array $data)
    {
        /** @var SourceItemInterface $sourceItem */
        $sourceItem = $this->sourceItemFactory->create();
        $sourceItem->setSourceCode($data[self::CSV_SOURCE_CODE]);
        $sourceItem->setSku($data[self::CSV_SKU]);
        $sourceItem->setStatus($data[self::CSV_STATUS]);
        $sourceItem->setQuantity((float)$data[self::CSV_QTY]);
        $sourceItem->save();

        return $product;
    }

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to set quantity to specific inventory source:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$sourceItem1 = $objectManager->create('Magento\InventoryApi\Api\Data\SourceItemInterface');

$sourceItem1->setSku('product_sku1');
$sourceItem1->setSourceCode('inventory_source_code1');
$sourceItem1->setQuantity(10);
$sourceItem1->setStatus(1);

$sourceItem2 = $objectManager->create('Magento\InventoryApi\Api\Data\SourceItemInterface');
$sourceItem2->setSku('product_sku1');
$sourceItem2->setSourceCode('inventory_source_code2');
$sourceItem2->setQuantity(20);
$sourceItem2->setStatus(1);


$sourceItemSave = $objectManager->get('\Magento\InventoryApi\Api\SourceItemsSaveInterface');
$sourceItemSave->execute([ $sourceItem1, $sourceItem2]);
```